Retrosynthesis of 2,5,8-trimethylnonan-5-ol
They ask us to suggest a retrosynthesis of 2,5,8-trimethylnonan-5-ol:

So I went through my course slides, and I found this:

Translation: verwende Grignard = use Grignard
My question is: Can I actually do that for the molecule given above? This is the only retrosynthesis suggestion I found in our course slides for a Hydroxyl (OH) and methyl group on the same carbon. So we would "cut" a bond like following:

For the left molecule, we would have 2-methylbutane with a Grignard Reagent on the last (fourth) carbon. So we would have 1-(bromomagnesium)-3-methylbutane. And for the right molecule, we would have a ketone $(\ce{C=O})$ instead of the hydroxyl group $(\ce{C-OH})$. Thus, retrosynthesis of 2,5,8-trimethylnonan-5-ol would be as follows:

So my second question is: Is what I did actually correct or did I mess up completely and we should do the Retrosynthesis in another way? They don't give out solutions so I have no idea if that's what they expect.

Maybe you could use the symmetry, using two equivalents of the Grignard to add 10 carbons to a 2-carbon precursor. Do you know a reaction where a Grignard adds to the same carbon atom twice? Spoiler

There are 3 retrosynthetic approaches for your given reaction. One of them is what you are suggesting.  Second one is using 2,8-dimethylnon-5-one with methyl magnesium iodide (commercially available). The easiest one is what Karsten suggesting using ethyl acetate as carbonyl reagent. For safe side, you may give all three as your solution.

@Karsten I thought you can do that with Nitrile (R-C≡N). But it doesn't seem to appear on your linked webpage. But with Nitrile we could add two Grignard reagents, and so the molecule could be built up. Mathew Mahindaratne seems to suggest that ethyl acetate could work instead of Nitrile, do I understand that correctly ?

@MathewMahindaratne Does ethyl acetate work like Nitrile (R-C≡N) in this case ? I knew we can use Nitrile to add a Grignard twice but I'm not sure about ethyl acetate, I will look it up

Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. That works perfectly. For example, are using that method in TAMU for Organic Chemistry II laboratory (using excess Grignard reagent).

@wengen I was thinking about adding to a carboxylic acid chloride. Depending whether this is a dry exercise or you actually have to implement it, other methods might be preferable. Don't forget to cite this page if "they" require sources when "they" asked you to solve this problem. There is a nifty button under the question.

Thank you very much for your help Mathew Mahndaratne and Karsten ! Feel free to post an answer if you want, otherwise I will answer in two days so the question doesn't appear anymore in the unanswered section

Who is "they"? $\ce{}$

Grignard di-addition to esters - scroll down this page for mechanism  https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_(Morsch_et_al.)/21%3A_Carboxylic_Acid_Derivatives-_Nucleophilic_Acyl_Substitution_Reactions/21.06%3A_Chemistry_of_Esters

@Waylander Thank you for the link !
